# SQLSTATE = 42S02: Native Error Code = -204: Msg = [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0204N "SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO" is an undefined name

Tags: db2, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am trying to run a DataStage job code of 8.7 version on 11.7.
job has below stages:

```
     output file1                 output File2
           ^                            ^
           |                            |
Db2 --> transform <-- hash file --> transform <-- Db2
```

In 8.7 Datstage the job is working fine. But in 11.7 it is throwing below error:

```
Exception thrown from CC_DB2Connection::getVersionServerPtf, file CC_DB2Connection.cpp, line 3848: DB2 function SQLExecDirect() failed:  SQLSTATE = 42S02: Native Error Code = -204: Msg = [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0204N  "SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

I tried look into SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO table in DB2 throw Dbeaver(SQL tool) and I am able to perform select statement on it through my userid/password(diff from what is being used in job).

I tried connecting to the server through command line using the userid/password used in job and able to perform select statement on SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO.

Request you to please guide me through it as I am doing code migration of several projects on 11.7 version from 8.7 and this is a blocker for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your job design looks like a server job. Make sure you compiled it with the new engine version. Also make sure you're using the correct database server and user. (Are you accidently pointing to another database?) Test it directly in the job design using 'test connection' and 'view data' on the actual system where the error occurs. Also chek if you're using the correct job parameter variables and values.

Comment: When I try to do TEST CONNECTION in any of the DB2 stage, it is throwing me above error again. Everything is same just the version changes, I tried matching the parameters as well but everything is cloned. I am not really sure where should I look.

Comment: Since you don't get a connection error but a table/view not found, for me it seems that you're on the wrong database. IMHO the stage shouldn't get that far without a functioning connection to a database. Maybe somone else has another idea, sry. Besides that I suggest to go for parallel jobs, which of course would generate quite some migration and redesign work, but it also would prepare for the next gen of DataStage.

Comment: Or, well... another user with lack of permissions.

Comment: Its not a table/view not found error, its a " is an undefined name" error which I think is related to permission somewhere. But I am not really sure where to look at. Plus, I cannot design the job newly as it is already working in production and doing that will require high level permission and approvals. I need to make this job work instead of creating a new one. Can you refer me to someone who would be able to help me out.

Comment: _not found_ and _undefined name_ in this case means technically the same. Another possibility is that your database uses _trusted context_ connections meaning that your datastage engine _machine_ needs permissions, too. I would refer you to your dba to clairify that thought.